# Removing log files except for the most recent 5 using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel VBA worksheet creates logs in a directory. Currently, the logs keep building up as I do not remove them.

However, now I would like to only keep the most recent 5. My logs are created with filenames as below:

`<worksheet_name>_YYYYMMDD_HH_MM_SS.log`

My current method of doing this job is to throw these logs into an array, sort the array, and keep only the first 5.

My question is this: Does anyone have a better method of keeping only the most 5 recent log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a workable solution.  Use the FileSystemObject library to gather all the log files, then loop thru them.

One option: you could try deleting based on Date Created or Date Modified, i.e. if the file was created over x days ago, delete it.

Also, I don't know how important these files are, but you may want to just move them to a folder called Archive instead of outright deleting them.

Comment: +1 for letting me know about `FileSystemObject`, learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

One system we used a while ago was to keep e.g. 5 log files with a "gap". So you would create the first 5 log files:

Files: 1,2,3,4,5

Then, on the 6th day, your gap is at 6, so create 6 and delete 1

Files:    ,2,3,4,5,6

The gap is now at 1. So for the next day, create 1, and delete 2

Files: 1, ,3,4,5,6

The gap is now at 2. So for the next day, create 2, and delete 3

Files: 1,2, ,4,5,6

etc etc
i.e. "Find the Gap" *, fill it with the new file, then delete the one after it.

Just an idea.

_* (yes this is a bad joke referring to the London Underground)

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an old question, since I needed this exact solution I figured I would add it here. This code assumes that the file name ends in something that is sortable by string comparison, so that could be files of a format SomeName_YYYY-MM-DD. Twenty-four hour time stamps can be incorporated as well. This process does not rename any files, so any incremental numeric scheme will need to be carefully managed by other code (i.e. you want to add _1, _2, etc. to the file names).

Note that this solution leverages collections which serve this purpose much better than an array.

```
Public Sub CleanBackups(filePathAndBaseName As String, fileExtension As String, maxCopiesToKeep As Integer)
'
'   Calling Example
'       CleanBackups "C:\Temp\MyLog", ".txt", 5
'
'       The above example would keep only the 5 versions of the file pattern "C:\Temp\MyLog*.txt"
'         that are "LARGEST" in terms of a string comparison.
'       So if MyLog_1.txt thru MyLog_9.txt exist, it will delete MyLog_1.txt - MyLog_4.txt
'         and leave MyLog_5.txt - MyLog_9.txt
'       Highly recommend using pattern MyLog_{YYYY-MM-DD_HhNn}.txt

    Dim pathOnly As String
    Dim foundFileName As String
    Dim oldestFileIndex As Integer
    Dim iLoop As Integer

    Dim fileNameCollection As New Collection

    pathOnly = Left(filePathAndBaseName, InStrRev(filePathAndBaseName, "\"))
    foundFileName = Dir(filePathAndBaseName & "*" & fileExtension, vbNormal)

    Do While foundFileName <> ""
        fileNameCollection.Add foundFileName
        foundFileName = Dir
    Loop

    Do While fileNameCollection.Count > maxCopiesToKeep
    ' Find oldest file, using only the name which assumes it ends with YYYY-MM-DD and optionally a 24-hour time stamp
        oldestFileIndex = 1

        For iLoop = 2 To fileNameCollection.Count
            If StrComp(fileNameCollection.Item(iLoop), fileNameCollection.Item(oldestFileIndex), vbTextCompare) < 0 Then
                oldestFileIndex = iLoop
            End If
        Next iLoop

        Kill pathOnly & "\" & fileNameCollection.Item(oldestFileIndex)
        fileNameCollection.Remove oldestFileIndex
    Loop

End Sub
```